# animating from regular text to bold in a textview

Tags: android, textview, android-animation

I have a `TextView` that I switch between regular and **bold** styles. When it switches between regular and bold, I would like it to animate with a 'grow' and 'shrink' accordingly, rather than just switch. How can this be done?

Note I am not changing the size of the textview, I am just changing the text style.

The textview can display more than one text, so I cannot use drawables.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: @Amir not trying to change the size, just the style from regular to bold.

Comment: have you tried to use the drawable?

Comment: @Zuhrain the textview text is not always the same, so I don't believe I can use drawables.

Comment: how about this one. make the textstyle changes by programmatically: `textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);`

Comment: @Zuhrain yes that sets it to bold, but I would like it to animate between regular and bold, rather than just be a discrete change.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do a trick with [the CSS font-weight property](http://htmldog.com/references/css/properties/font-weight/) and a loop incrementing the value step by step. As you can see on the documentation, you'll see an effect on the font every 100

**Example** :

```
boldTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p style='font-weight: " + x + ";'>Text</p>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
```